# Scala get Array from array in Map

Tags: arrays, list, scala, dictionary

i new at scala,  there is the Map: (it so, cos i get huge Map like this from mongo)

```
val test = Map(
      "temp" -> Array( 1,
        Array(
          1, "kisa"
        )
      )
    )
```

How i can get "kisa"  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So... let me explain,

```
val test = Map(
  "temp" -> Array( 1,
    Array(
      1, "kisa"
    )
  )
)
```

Now `test` is `scala.collection.immutable.Map[ String, Array[ Any ] ]` which means a `map` from `String` to `Array[ Any ]`.

So... to get value associated with key - "temp", you do

```
val tempVal = test( "temp" )
```

Now, `tempVal` is of type `Array[ Any ]` and its value is `Array( 1, Array( 1, kisa ) )`

What we want is the second ( index = 1 ) entry in this array.

```
val secondEntry = tempVal( 1 )
```

Now... `secondEntry` has type `Any` and its value is `Array( 1, Kisa )`... we can not obtain `Kisa` now... first we have to cast this from `Any` to `Array[ Any ]`.

```
val secondEntryArray = secondEntry.asInstanceOf[ Array[ Any ] ]
```

Now... `secondEntryArray` is of type `Array[ Any ]` and its value is `Array( 1, kisa )`

Now, we have to get second entry from this array,

```
val kisaVal = secondEntryArray( 1 )
```

Now... `kisaVal` has type `Any` and its value is `kisa`. You know that it is a `String` and you probably want it as a `String`... so lets type-cast it to a String,

```
val kisaString = kisaVal.asInstanceOf[ String ]
```

And you are done.

To do it simply in one line....

```
val kisa = test( "temp" )( 1 ).asInstanceOf[ Array[ Any ] ]( 1 ).asInstanceOf[ String ]
```

Comment: I had that trouble for 2 days. im newbee at compile-languae (came from ruby for more app-prefomance) THANKS U A LOT!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Pattern matching is better than `asInstanceOf`:

```
test("temp") match {
  case Array(_, Array(_, s: String)) =>
    s
}
```

Voila.

If you want to bind the result to a variable, instead of just returning it, you can even shorten it to:

```
val Array(_, Array(_, s: String)) = test("temp")
```

to which the Scala REPL responds:

```
s: String = kisa
```

Comment: Surely you are right... but don't you think that's mixing of one more concept making the code even more opaque for a beginner.

Comment: No, I don't agree. Pattern-matching is beginner-level Scala. It's one of the first things new folks should be learning.

Comment: I agree Pattern matching is an important concept in Scala. I am just talking about mixing of multiple concepts making the code elegant, idiomatic but  cryptic to new programmers.

Comment: Pattern-matching - is the right-way!  I read some guides from twitter-scala-school, and pattern-matching more much better, that .asInstanceOf because it work on compile-time, and .asInstanceOf  work on run-time

Comment: @Legendary I know very well that pattern matching is very good and I almost always use pattern matching. And I am happy to know that you are making progress in learning and understanding Scala. But `pattern-matching` and `asInstnaceOf` are very different tools, though they overlap but they meant for very different purposes. `.asInstanceOf` comes in use when we have to deal with lots of Java objects, which do not play well with `pattern-matching`.

Comment: @Legendary Scala pattern matching actually uses something called `Extractors` for `deconstructing` some Scala object such as `Tuple`, `List` etc into their members ( generally or some smaller chunks ). Scala provides `Extractors` for all `case class`es  and things in Standard library by default. So.. For all other things you will have to define some `ìmplicit` instance of corresponding `Extractor` to be able to use pattern matching. And defining `Extractors` for some `data-structures` can be very much involving. Also, you will want to define your extractor only if you are reusing them a lot.

Comment: i get it, ty for ur ans, i will read more about Tuple and Options

Comment: pattern matching works just fine with just Java objects. that's no justification for using `asInstanceOf`.

Comment: @SethTisue Well... Apples can not be compared to Oranges. Yes, both of them provide nutrition and are good for health and hey have lots of things in common. Yet you can neither always replace Oranges by Apples nor vice-verse. I am not saying that you should eat only Oranges or only Apples. Both of these are great fruits and have their own benefits and problems. You would be wiser to consider both for their properties and eat the one which better fits the circumstances.